# Sails Socket adapter 'Redis' not talking with Redis

Tags: sockets, redis, publish-subscribe, sails.io.js

How to achieve redis pubsub in sails, where redis and sails should communicate each other.

I am using sails 0.11.0 and my sails.socket config.

adapter: 'socket.io-redis',
host: 'localhost',
port: 6379,

to achieve redis as my socket store, where User.publishCreate and redis.on('user', msg).. i assume this two will communicate...

Comment: To be more clear.. 

Sails suggested adapter 'socket.io-redis' communicate with redis, but the room id will be like 'socket.io#Fgt5'

In case if am trying to publish through external script... 

ex: db.publish('user', 'important');

How sails socket will get notified and how it will identify ?